# How do I take transpose of a 2D array without declaring another array?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

array:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

The output I want:

```
1 4
2 5
3 6
```

My code:

```
for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < col; j++) {
    temp = matrix[j][i];
    matrix[j][i] = matrix[i][j];
    matrix[i][j] = temp;
  }
}

for (i = 0; i < col; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
    cout << setw(5) << matrix[i][j];
  }
  cout << endl;
}
```

where number of rows and columns, and the elements of array were taken from the user.

The output I am getting:

```
1 2
4 5
3 6
```

Any and every help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try making `for (j = i; j < col; j++)` instead of `for (j = 0; j < col; j++)` in your matrix loop, because you should not go back to values that were already changed.

Comment: On entering row 1= 1 2, row 2= 3 4 and row 3= 5 6. This solution gives junk in the place of last column of transpose matrix.

Comment: @M.M. are you using array or vector?

Comment: I am using an array